# Can't execute git command from bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute git commands from a bash script.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "commit and push all files in this folder: "

INPUTPATH=""
FILENAME="README2"
PATH=""

if [ -s text.txt ]
then
    echo "file is not empty"

    INPUTPATH=$(<text.txt)
    #echo "$INPUTPATH"
else
          read INPUTPATH
   echo "$INPUTPATH" > text.txt

   
fi

PATH="$INPUTPATH/$FILENAME"
for run in {1..10}; do
echo $RANDOM >> $PATH
done
cd $INPUTPATH && git commit -am "commit"
cd $INPUTPATH  && git status
```

The script work's fine, besides the last two commands.

these are the error messages:

line 25: git: command not found
line 26: git: command not found

Comment: either you do not have `git` installed or your script is not able to find the `git` executable when it runs. If you have installed it - Do a `which git` to get the absolute path of the executable and replace `git` with the output of the command.

Comment: It seems that git is not installed in your system. can you try command `which git` and paste the output

Comment: Don't modify `$PATH`.

Comment: You're setting the PATH variable, the PATH variable contains paths to where executable files/commands are located (such as the git command), don't reset it.

Comment: It was the $PATH variable, thanks a lot